# How to remap a symbol to call a different function

Tags: linux, gcc, elf

I have an `ELF` shared object, and I want to modify it so that calls to the system function `memcpy` are actually routed through to a custom version of `memcpy`.

I've been researching and I have read about `PLT` Redirection and `ELF` Infection, but I'm still not sure how I can accomplish my goal.

Can anyone give me some hint and tips, or elaborate on the `PLT` Redirection and `ELF` Infection?

Regards,

Paul

Comment: Note that memcpy() may be intrinsic (inlined) in this .so and therefore can't be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the `-wrap` option to ld when you link your executable?  It should redirect the symbol so that all calls to the original function, including those inside libraries, will go to your replacement.

See [this example](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/using-ld-wrap-function-to-instrument-790444/).

[Edit: The above commenter is correct in pointing out that if the library inlined calls to memcpy, you have no recourse short of rebuilding the library.]